# Test Spring v5 with Junit v5, always got error @Autowired DAO as NullPoint

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, netbeans, junit5

In NetBeans IDE v14, I created a Spring v5 as Maven web app called User, it is running well connected via UserDAO to my local MySQL DB.

But now when today I added Junit 5 to test DAO, and web Controller, I am having issue in the test class at:
@Autowired private UserDAO userDao;
userDao always null, so I got NullPoint error.
With my POM.xml file, I did try JUnit 5, also JUnit 4, and different
versions of Spring, Hibernate xml, and JPA. Still getting the same
error: DAO field null.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/olap-servlet.xml")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"ca.i5i.user"})
public class UserDAOTest {
    private User user;
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDao;
    

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        user = new User();
        userDao = new UserDAOImpl();      
    }
 
    @Test
    public void testLoginUser(@Autowired UserDAO userDao) throws Exception {
        user.setUserName("u743");
        user.setPassword("pass743");
        logger.info("testLoginUser info: FirstName=" + user.getUserName() + ", LastName = " + user.getPassword() + ";");
        logger.info("testLoginUser userDao=" + userDao);

        User loginUser = userDao.loginUser(user);
        assertNotNull(loginUser.getId());
    }
```

Comment: It might easier to get an answer if you post your test. My guess is that your are writing unit test and not integration test. In unit test, application context is not loaded and has to be mocked using framework such as Spock and Mockito

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I thought this might work, but it did not work, that proves your opinion is correct: 
SpringExtension.getApplicationContext().getBean(UserDAO.class);

Comment: I added my test class code above, please let me know if more info needed, thanks

Comment: I just found out a fix as this:
public void testLoginUser(@Autowired UserDAO userDao) throws Exception {

So now I am all set, thanks anyway.